# What is exit code 3221225781 on windows?

Tags: windows, dll

What is exit code `3221225781` (also `0xC0000135` or `-1073741515`) on windows?

Current google results will lead to pages with questions about specific software without addressing what this error code is.

Comment: `0xC0000135` is `STATUS_DLL_NOT_FOUND`.

Answer (score 0):

This error indicates windows was unable to find a dll needed by your application.

Possible fixes include:

- Installing missing libraries
- Ensuring .dll files needed by your executable are in the same folder as your executable
- Or adding a folder to your system's PATH

Answer (score -1):

You can try reinstall Microsoft .NET Framework or Dll library. I had such a problem.
I can't say exactly which of these suited me. I was playing a game on BlueStacks emulator, after that the error started to occur. When I was looking for an answer in Google, I was recommended to replace this [library](https://error-dll.info/file/vkernel32dll) or download update .NET Framework from the [official Microsoft website](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=21).