# pgadmin error when restoring database from tar file

Tags: database, postgresql, pgadmin

I'm trying load a tar file using pgAdmin, but it's failing and all I get is exit code 3221225781. This code seems to indicate a missing dll [What is exit code 3221225781 on windows?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77219743/what-is-exit-code-3221225781-on-windows) but I'm not sure why this would be or what dll to look for.

[image: error message]

Comment: Run the command directly from the Windows command line and see if there is more information.

Answer (score 47, accepted):

Updating the path in pgAdmin fixed this.

Steps:
Select Databases > File > Preferences > Paths > Binary paths.
Then edit to `C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\15\bin.`

You'll need to use a different path if you're on a different version of PostgreSQL.

[image: Updating the path]

Comment: Seems to be incorrect binary paths as default then.

Answer (score 6):

You need to change the path in pgadmin. In my case, I have PostgreSQL 16.

Go to File/Preferences/Paths/Binary_paths

Choose your PostgreSQL version and change to the binary path as:

C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\16\bin.

Answer (score 0):

For Me, I have installed several postgress versions:10,13 and 14.
And I've been using version 10 for learning purpose.

[image]
So I have copied the bin folder path from 'C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\10\bin'

Then set this path as the default
[image]

BEFORE UPDATE :

[image]

AFTER UPDATE PATH :

[image]