# pgAdmin 4 Restoring File Failed (exit code: 3221225781)

Tags: postgresql, pgadmin, pgadmin-4

[image: Picture]

Hi guys, I am taking the Udemy course on SQL and trying to restore a tar file to put into my dvdrental database in pgAdmin 4 but it always gives the same error. I've tried restarting my computer and trying different versions of postgreSQL with no success. Any help would be appreciated, thanks!

Comment: Use a different tool, like pg_restore: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/app-pgrestore.html

Comment: Where are you seeing the exit code you report in your title?  What do you see when you click on the sheet of paper icon in the processes table? What version of pgAdmin4 is this?

Comment: Use following URL to solve this problem. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77462578/pgadmin-error-when-restoring-database-from-tar-file